# Visual Studio Sharepoint 2013 Workflow connect to other site

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015, sharepoint-workflow

Hi I'm developing a Sharepoint workflow in Visual Studio 2015 with XAML designer deployed in SITE B Library, but I want to create a LinkToDocument file into another SharePoint SITE A. I can do it programmatically with this code but I don't know how to get another site using the XAML designer tool or instead how to execute my code in a Sharepoint Workflow. I've tried using CodeActivity but I have to do some server side configurations and I'm not allowed to do it.

By code:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ())
{
    //Get SITE A
    SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sharepointdomain/sites/siteA");
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    SPDocumentLibrary library =(SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["MyLibrary"];
    SPFieldUrlValue document = new SPFieldUrlValue()
    {
        Url = "http://sharepointdomain/sites/siteB/" + currentItemName, //Link URL
        Description = "Link description " 
    };

    //This class creates the file into SITE A
    cratedFile = LinkADocumento.CrearArchivoLinkToDocument(library, "New File Name ", document);

});
```